# multi byte data transmission at once in I2C and Spi

Tags: embedded, i2c, spi

I would like to ask, can we send multiple bytes (10-20 bytes or more) at one data transmission. With one data transmission I meant with single "start" communication bit.
("start bit" + "multi byte data" + "stop")

or do we have to stop transmission after every single byte and start new transmission to send rest of the data?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is not only possible but essential in most use-cases of I2C.

In SPI there is no start/stop but sequences of bytes are framed with the chip-select signal.  It is normal to send many bytes per frame.